# Updating label with data from thread

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-safety

I am trying to update a label in windows forms. The action is happening in a separate class but while the action is happening on a separate class. The label should be updated, but things seem to be not working. Kindly assist

Below is the Back code of the form ProcessingUI

```
public partial class ProcessingUI : Form
{
    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartProcessingTask();
    }

     private void StartProcessingTask()
    {
        if (_isRunning)
            return;

        _isRunning = true;

        _taskToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (_isRunning)
                {

                    var data = _processing.Processdata(lblCounter, _taskToken);
                    if (data.Success)
                        _isRunning = false;
                    if (_taskToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                }

            });

    }

    public delegate void SetStatusCallback();
    public void UpdateStatus()
    {
       lblCounter.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {

            lblCounter.Text += new EventHandler(_processing.Raise);
        });
    }
}
```

Then here is a separate class that has the action, basically its just updating.
Now on update I just want to pass the record that is being updated. So i call the Method from the form and use it in this class.

```
 public class Processing
    {
         public Results Processdata(CancellationTokenSource taskToken)
        {
        foreach (var record in dataCases)
                {
           //Doing other things here like updating
             new ProcessingUI().UpdateStatus();//This is the method I am calling from the form.
             get(record.RequestReference);
            }

        }

         public string get(string msg)
                 {
                 return msg;
               } 
          public void Raise(object sender, EventArgs e)
              {
                 get("hello");

                 }

    }
```

Comment: why new ProcessingUI()? surely you just need to set in your processing class an event, and then in the form assign to the event, and have it update using the updateStatus.

Comment: @BugFinder, i updated the code, but not sure if am doing it as you suggested

Comment: Nope way off base.  Look up setting events. You can do it either way, have class processing have an event, or the form, it makes more sense for it to be the processing class.. so, make an event I dunno OnReport .. form subscribes to that and does  the updatestatus (and tests if it needs to invoke that) .. then in your for loop in the processing class do if assigned OnReport then OnReport(the update string) ...

Answer (score 0):

Using Progress to handle cross-thread access

```
public class Processing
{
    public Results ProcessData(IProgress<string> statusReporter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        foreach (var record in dataCases)
        {
            // Doing other things here like updating

            // Update the status:
            statusReporter.OnReport(record.RequestReference);

            // Stop if the task has been cancelled:
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
}

public partial class ProcessingUI : Form
{
    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartProcessingTask();
    }

    private void StartProcessingTask()
    {
        if (_isRunning)
            return;

        _isRunning = true;
        _taskToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

        CancellationToken cancellationToken = _taskToken.Token;
        IProgress<string> statusReporter = new Progress<string>(UpdateStatus);

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (_isRunning)
            {
                var data = _processing.ProcessData(lblCounter, cancellationToken);
                if (data.Success)
                {
                    _isRunning = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void UpdateStatus(string message)
    {
        lblCounter.Text = message;    
    }
}
```